# Is this true lemma in the proof of momentum map $J$ is a Poisson map?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry, moment-map

Suppose $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold equipped with $G$-action $\Phi : G \times M \to M$. Assume $\Phi^*_g \omega = \omega$.

Let $J$ be an equivariant momentum map of $M$, $J : M \to \mathrm{Lie}(G)^*$. In here, equivariance of $J$ means
\begin{align}
 \mathrm{Ad}_g^* J = J \circ \Phi_{g}
\end{align}

Then, does it always hold,
\begin{align}
J_{\mathrm{d}_{J(x)}f}(x) = f \circ J(x)
\end{align} for any $x \in M$ and $f : C^\infty(\mathrm{Lie}(G)^*, \mathbb{R})$? In here, I use the identification,
\begin{align}
 \mathrm{d}_{J(x)}f : T\mathrm{Lie}(g)^* \cong \mathrm{Lie}(g)^*  \overset{linear}{\to} \mathbb{R}
\end{align}

If $f$ is linear functional, *i.e.* $f \in \mathrm{Lie}(G)$, then I can show this. But, does it holds for general case?

If it's not true, how can I approach to prove
$$
\{ f \circ J, g \circ J \}_M = \{ f, g \}_{\mathrm{Lie}(G)^*} \circ J
$$ where
$$
\{ f, g\}_M = \omega(X_f, X_g)\\
\{ f, g\}_{\mathrm{Lie}(G)^*} = \mu \mapsto \mu([\mathrm{d}_\mu f , \mathrm{d}_\mu g])
$$?

The reason why I tried to prove the above lemma is,
I get the result that It's enough to prove
$$
\{f \circ J, g \circ J\}_M = \{J_{\mathrm{d}_{J(x)}f}(x), J_{\mathrm{d}_{J(x)}g}(x)  \}_M
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your claim that for all $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^{*})$ and $x\in M$,
$$
J_{d_{J(x)}f}(x)=f(J(x))
$$
is not true. For instance, if $f\equiv 1$ then the LHS is zero, while the RHS is equal to $1$.

Note that $J:(M,\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{M})\rightarrow (\mathfrak{g}^{*},\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{\mathfrak{g}^{*}})$ matches the Poisson brackets exactly when for all $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^{*})$, the Hamiltonian vector fields $X_{f}$ and $X_{J^{*}f}$ are $J$-related. In fact, it suffices to check this condition for functions $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^{*})$ whose differentials span the cotangent spaces of $\mathfrak{g}^{*}$. Such a collection is given by $\{h_{v}:v\in\mathfrak{g}\}$, where
$h_{v}\in C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^{*})$ denotes the linear function on $\mathfrak{g}^{*}$ corresponding with $v\in\mathfrak{g}$.

1. For all $v\in\mathfrak{g}$, we have $J_{v}=J^{*}(h_{v})$. Taking Hamiltonian vector fields, we get
   $$
   v^{\sharp}=X_{J^{*}(h_{v})},
   $$
   where $v^{\sharp}$ denotes the fundamental vector field of the action corresponding to $v$.
2. Show that $v^{\sharp}$ and $X_{h_{v}}$ are $J$-related. This is where equivariance of $J$ comes into play.
3. We now know that $X_{J^{*}(h_{v})}$ and $X_{h_{v}}$ are $J$-related, so the conclusion follows.

Comment: Actually, I have been wandering arounding here. _In fact, it suffices to check this condition for functions $f \in C^\infty(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ whose differentials span the cotangent spaces of $\mathfrak{g}^*$_. Why it's sufficient?

Comment: Being a Poisson map is a pointwise statement. It means checking that $$d_{x}J\circ \Pi_{M}^{\sharp}\circ(d_{x}J)^{*}=\Pi_{\mathfrak{g}^{*}}^{\sharp}$$ as maps $T^{*}_{J(x)}\mathfrak{g}^{*}\rightarrow T_{J(x)}\mathfrak{g}^{*}$. This equality follows as soon as we check it for a basis of $T^{*}_{J(x)}\mathfrak{g}^{*}$, for instance $\{d_{J(x)}h_{v}\}$ as in my answer.